# Kopano LDAP unable to login when username has special character

Tags: postfix, ldap, openldap, sasl

Ok, so I currently have a Kopano server working with Openldap to manage logins. The problem I currently have is that if I decide to define a user's login as his email, I can't send a message via Thunderbird (incoming server is an IMAP server going over port 993 and the outgoing server is SMTP with STARTTLS over port 587). Authentication keeps failing. I.E. like below:

```
username: john@test.com 
password: whatever
```

Logs show me this:

```
Jun  6 17:32:50 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: connect from modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]
Jun  6 17:32:50 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: Anonymous TLS connection established from modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Jun  6 17:32:50 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Jun  6 17:32:50 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: warning: modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jun  6 17:32:50 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: warning: modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jun  6 17:32:54 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: disconnect from modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]
```

However, the strange part is that if I change the credentials to this:

```
username: john
password: whatever
```

Now I can send my emails normally and the logs show me this:

```
Jun  6 17:34:13 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: connect from modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]
Jun  6 17:34:14 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: Anonymous TLS connection established from modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Jun  6 17:34:14 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: 27DF7307CBFF: client=modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=edastous
Jun  6 17:34:14 courrier postfix/cleanup[23195]: 27DF7307CBFF: message-id=<5ce1fb94-096b-e613-5686-77a2b631e6eb@addlys.com>
Jun  6 17:34:14 courrier postfix/qmgr[1843]: 27DF7307CBFF: from=<edastous@addlys.com>, size=780, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  6 17:34:14 courrier postfix/submission/smtpd[23440]: disconnect from modemcable202.76-70-69.static.videotron.ca[69.70.76.202]
Jun  6 17:34:15 courrier postfix/smtp[23447]: 27DF7307CBFF: to=<anonymous@hotmail.com>, relay=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.49.33]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.14/0.02/0.4/0.98, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <5ce1fb94-096b-e613-5686-77a2b631e6eb@addlys.com> [InternalId=37104222519256, Hostname=DM3NAM05HT118.eop-nam05.prod.protection.outlook.com] 6330 bytes in 0.280, 22.047 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Jun  6 17:34:15 courrier postfix/qmgr[1843]: 27DF7307CBFF: removed
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

EDIT: Here is the result of `postconf -n | grep sasl`

```
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Comment: Please edit `postconf -n | grep sasl` into your question.

Comment: @84104 I just did as you asked

Answer (score 0):

You're mentioning that SASL auth works until you change the username from "john" to "john@test.com", right? Unfortunately, you did not post your SASL configuration, e.g. `/etc/sysconfig/saslauthd`, thus I just can assume that you're not starting up `saslauthd` using `-r`, but without (because that's the default). See also [man 8 saslauthd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/saslauthd) for what `-r` is doing.